How to align rows within cell in Latex?
I am a kind of new user in Latex and there is a problem I am trying to fix. Here is my latex code for that;
\begin{tabular}{p{3cm} p{8cm} p{6cm}}
    {\rmfamily\scshape \textnormal{CONTACT \newline INFORMATION}} & 
    \textnormal{XXX} \newline 
    \textnormal{YYY} \newline
    \textnormal{ZZZ} \newline 
    \textnormal{AAA} & 
    \parbox[t]{6cm}{
        \textnormal{Email:} \href{link}{link.com} \\
        \textnormal{Website:} \href{link}{linknknknknknkkn.com}}
\end{tabular}

This code produces this output;

And, what I am trying to fix is I would like to be able to align hyperlinked email and website address so that they could you be vertically aligned. How I can manage it?
Additionally I do not understand why \schape does not work for "CONTACT INFORMATION" to make it small caps. So, if you can comment on that too, I would be glad for that. Thanks beforehand.

Welcome to TeX.SE. About your final question: \scshape converts lowercase letters to small-cap letters; by construction, it does nothing to uppercase letters. Moreover, \textnormal nullifies whatever effect \scshape has; do you maybe want \upshape? What you want, in short, is either {\scshape contact information} or, more likely, {\scshape Contact Information}.

thanks, it did workout. Do you have any comments for the first question about the aligning?

Assuming you want the links to line up, and the labels to be right aligned, try this for the first line: \phantom{Website:}\llap{Email:} <address>

Something like this?

\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{tabularx} % for 'tabularx' environment and 'X' column type
\usepackage{calc} % for '\widthof' macro
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}
%% define a bespoke column type (for first column):
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\widthof{\textsc{#1}}}}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\normalfont % just in case
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} P{Information} X r @{}}

    \scshape Contact Information 
    & 
    XXX \newline 
    YYY \newline
    ZZZ \newline 
    AAA 
    & 
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{} r @{\hspace{2mm}} l @{}}
         Email & \href{link}{link.com} \\
         Website & \href{link}{linknknknknknkkn.com}
    \end{tabular}

\end{tabularx}

\end{document}


Thank you so much! That was definitely what I was looking for!!!
